# Configure remote Laravel app to be accessible from browser

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, centos7

All the laravel projects I worked on were installed/configured started by other people. A long time ago I managed to install a Laravel project on a Windows machine using WAMP and it was easier as far as I remember.
I recently received access to a clean droplet from digitalocean.com with Centos 7 installed. I think a droplet is something like a VPS. You have an IP, and SSH access
After some headache I managed to successfully install laravel using composer. I have also installed mysql and apache(httpd)
Now I have

> /var/www/laravel

folder, with the installation of the latest Laravel (5.3)

I went inside /var/www/ and called

> composer create-project laravel/laravel mypro

Now, I have a laravel app scheleton of a new application at

> /var/www/mypro

I would like to access it from a browser so I can start working on it, but I do not know what I need to do. There are many tutorials on how to do that but they are very confusing for me.

What must I do next in order to be able to see the results of what I am working on?
If , in the browser, I access now the droplet by IP, like

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I get

> Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Same if I add to the URL the name of my app like

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mypro

I believe I must configure the httpd ? Or maybe move the project's folder somewhere else?

I tried moving my project folder inside /var/www/html folder, so

> /var/www/html/mypro

and now when I try to access the url I receive an empty page (view-source of the browser page returns also an empty page)
I even tried

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mypro/server.php

since there is a server.php file in the root of my project folder... same result

I even added a conf to the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ folder called mypro.conf where I added these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mypro
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mypro/public"
   <Directory /var/www/html/mypro/public>
      AllowOverride all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Nothing new happens
I did "service httpd restart" everytime a changed something.

I even tried

php artisan serve --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --port 8000

and tried the url http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000

Now I get "Unable to connect" page from the browser so I stopped the "serve"

What is it that I have to do in order to be able to finally start working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is way how i do it on Ubutnu 16.04 (It can be done with some changes on Centos).

Update your package repo.

```
sudo apt update
```

Update packeges.

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Install PHP

```
apt install php
```

Install apache2

```
apt install apache2
```

Install PHP Plugins

```
apt install php-mbstring php-pdo php-tokenizer php-xml php-mcrypt php-gd libapache2-mod-php php-curl php-mysql
```

Enable mcrypt

```
phpenmod mcrypt

a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart Apache Server

```
service apache2 restart
```

Install Composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Install Git

```
apt install git
```

Install mysql-server

```
apt install mysql-server
```

Install Phpmyadmin (Optional)

```
apt install phpmyadmin
```

Install zip & unzip

```
apt install zip unzip
```

Now create apache virtual host configuration for your website.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

touch pqr.xyz.com.conf
```

The basic content of is pqr.xyz.com.conf

```
#content of pqr.xyz.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName pqr.xyz.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@xyz.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pqr.xyz.com/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/pqr.xyz.com>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now goto /var/www/html

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

Create a directory with your website name

```
mkdir pqr.xyz.com
```

Now add a user because it is not good idea to work with composer as root while creating laravel project.

```
adduser admin --ingroup admin
```

Now make admin as owner of this directory

```
chown -R admin pqr.xyz.com
```

**Now login as admin**

go to /var/www/html

```
cd /var/www/html
```

Install Laravel using composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel pqr.xyz.com

cd /var/www/html/pqr.xyz.com
```

Now your storage and bootstrap directory should have write permission for apache 2 server so make apache owner of these two directories.

```
chown -R www-data storage

chown -R www-data bootstrap
```

**Now login as root**

Activate pqr.xyz.com.conf

```
a2dissite 000-default.conf

service apache2 reload

a2ensite shopperstock.eveningx.com.conf

service apache2 reload

service apache2 restart
```

**It may not be the best way to work with any larave project , So feel free to comment or suggest an edit.**

Comment: So if you read the question, you will understand that I already installed mysql, php, apache, unzip, git and laravel. I also created the project. In centos I have httpd service and apache user but other than that I did everything you suggest I would do. My httpd conf file (mypro.conf) is located in another location (like mentioned in the question) but contains all the relevant parts from what you suggest. It still does not work. Any suggestions on how to proceed next? (For CENTOS please)

Comment: It might be something about htaccess... or other config files... ?

Comment: It seems that apache is unable to find your public directory. So did you activated your apache configuration file as i did in last section of my answer?  I think the problem is with your apache virtual host config file .You should check apache log files . In ubuntu apache log files are located at /var/log/apache2/error.log  .

Comment: Following your recommendation, I looked into the apache log files and discovered my problem. So my configuration is good after all, but i had to do a "php artisan config:cache" and a "php artisan cache:clear". Thank you for steering me into the right direction

Comment: Most welcome @user1137313 , I am glad that it helped you.